# Безопасное кодирование байт в строку типа base64 или base58

Tags: c#, base64

Какие в c# есть варианты кодирования последовательности байт в строковую форму, кроме base64?

Вариант с base64 устраивает почти всем, но у него в символах алфавита используется несколько неудобных знаков. Мне мешает символ '=', ещё [на википедии упоминается](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), что возможны проблемы с передачей base64-кодированной строки в url.

Как возможный вариант замены рассматриваю [base58](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58), которая упоминается там же на википедии и которая используется в некоторых биткоин-прокотолах. У неё на выходе возможны только варианты букв и цифр. Жаль, что в C# включили именно base64, а не base58, придётся подключать какой-нибудь пакет.

Есть ли какие-то ещё варианты? Есть ли допустим base32 или base16?

Comment: Вероятно вам нужен Base64Url - такой же, которым JWT кодируют. ХЗ где он во фреймворке, я его не юзал, но загуглилось [вот это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urlencode?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Еще есть вот такой класс [Base64UrlEncoder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.base64urlencoder?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: @tym32167 Возможно, возможно... если любопытно, контекст вопроса можно посмотреть здесь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9496/213987

Answer (score 3):

Просто в голову пришла вот такая мысль

```
var str = "Hello, World!";
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)));
Console.WriteLine(encoded);

var decoded = Encoding.Default.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded)));
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно каждый байт кодировать как *16-ричное* число (2 символа).
Пример:

```
255 = 'FF'
165 = 'A5' 
0 = '00' 

и т.д.
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, плюс. Единственное -- длина строки выйдет больше, чем при кодировании base64.

Comment: Да, верно, он более избыточен, чем base64. Но по скорости кодирования-декодирования может быть быстрее (хотя, не уверен, надо тестировать).